# NodeJS Express post request always returning a 404 page, while it does return the correct page

Tags: node.js, express

Im pretty new to NodeJS and I'm writing a pagination script to display database data. To navigate to the next results im using form buttons because that's the only way I got the button interaction working with Node. I know that it is not the best practice but its sufficient for my needs right now :) However, when the user clicks the next/previous button, the post request does get called but always returns a 404 page, whilst if I copy that exact returning page and load it in myself, the page loads fine.

The post function:

```
  if(req.body.next){
    console.log(req.body.next)
    start += 100;
    console.log(start);
    get_products(start);
  }
  if(start >= 0 && req.body.prev){
    console.log(req.body.prev)
    start -= 100;
    console.log(start);
    get_products(start);
  }
});
```

The Pug form:

```
form(method = 'POST', action="/products")
     button(type='submit', name='prev', value='prev') previous
     button(type='submit', name='next', value='next') next
```

Output of the posts:

```
next
100
POST /products - - ms - -
prev
0
POST /products - - ms - -
next
100
POST /products - - ms - -
next
200
POST /products - - ms - -
next
300
POST /products - - ms - -
next
400
POST /products - - ms - -
prev
300
```

Comment: Where is the redirect call after you get the products with your `get_products` (e.g. `res.send` or `res.render`)?

Comment: Ahh that might be the problem. I will look into it tomorrow, thanks @montrealist

Comment: IMHO, you should be using GET and some parameters, rather than POST. Look up RESTful APIs. I think it's the POST processing that's causing the server to kick out an extra error as it doesn't know how to process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@montrealist's comment answered my question. I had to add a `res.render` to my post call to make the function refresh the page.

The updated post call:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.body.next){
    start += 100;
    get_products(start);
    res.render('products' , {
      title:"All products from index: " + (start - 99).toString(),
      products:products
    })
  }
  if(start >= 0 && req.body.prev){
    start -= 100;
    get_products(start);
    res.render('products' , {
      title:"All products from index: " + (start + 101).toString(),
      products:products
    })
  }
});
```